# "Rollup" fields in OpenTelemetry to sum values from child spans

Tags: python, django, open-telemetry, beeline

I'm currently in the process of migrating my Django application monitoring from [beeline](https://docs.honeycomb.io/getting-data-in/beeline/) to OpenTelemetry. One feature of beeline was the [`add_rollup_field` function](https://github.com/honeycombio/beeline-python/blob/main/beeline/trace.py#L258-L269) which can specify a field to be summed in a trace's root span. For example, if we add a `db.total_duration` rollup field, we can use that to sum all of the `db.duration` values for a root span.

What would be the best way to implement this in OpenTelemetry? Is there a good way to pass these values to parent spans and eventually to the root span? I've looked into Baggage but that appears to mainly be used to update a context for passing down the call stack, not up.